# Fourier transform of $\cos(\sqrt{r^2-t^2})$

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier Transform of $\cos(\sqrt{r^2-t^2})$ where r is a constant and t represents time. Please Help.

Comment: If you mention a few things you tried you're sure to get help.

Comment: Well I wrote down $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(\sqrt{r^2-t^2})e^{-2\pi jft}dt$ and then tried to use the cos exponential identity which did not help much, hope this helps.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?